# Set default mail sender on linux (PHP)

Tags: linux, php, smtp

Whenever i send an email in php with the `mail()` function, when i receive it as a user, the e-mail is shown as sent from "anonymous@MyServerName.local".

Now i want that to be sent from "mail-bot@mydomain.com" as a standard, without having to set the "From:" header in the `mail()` function when i send it.

I am not sure how to change this, so a little help would be nice.

I run CentOS 5.6 with a somewhat normal LAMP setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to set the originator mailbox in the message headers (to something other than the actual Unix/Linux account that the script runs under the aegis of) *is* by supplying a `From:` header to the `mail()` function.  There's no getting away from that.  The correct way to set the originator mailbox in the message *envelope* is either using environment variables within some shim script, pointed to by [`sendmail_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) and wrapped around the actual `sendmail` command, or using the UCB sendmail `-f` option.

Andrew's given you a Postfix environment variable to set in the shim script.  If you are using qmail you can in fact, per the [`qmail-inject` manual page](http://qmail.org/qmail-manual-html/man8/qmail-inject.html), set *both* header *and* envelope originators, with the `$QMAILUSER`+`$QMAILHOST`+`$QMAILNAME` (or `$MAILUSER`+`$MAILHOST`+`$MAILNAME` or `$USER`+`$MAILHOST`+`$NAME`) and `$QMAILSUSER`+`$QMAILSHOST` sets of environment variables respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The best options in the circumstance you request are probably either

- Use sendmail_from in php.ini
- or change the hostname of the host (either in /etc/hostname or the host name directive in your postfix/sendmail configuration)

Comment: The sendmail_from in the php.ini is only for windows, i run linux, but i'll take a look at option nr. 2...

Comment: Changing the hostname makes half the problem go away, the senders name is still anonymous, but other than that thanks. +1

Comment: Is 'anonymous' a valid user on your system? Typically in a LAMP setup the emails sent are from www-data@hostname or similar - the apache/php process owner.

Answer (score 1):

The [postfix sendmail man page](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) suggests using the `NAME` environment variable.

(Aside: the [die.net](http://linux.die.net) man page didn't mention it...)